# Protractor js test is unable to submit angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, protractor, automated-tests

I am writing test for my angularjs app using protractor test. The test fetches form elements enter values through sendKey() and tries to click the login button to see if it is being redirected to the correct page.

```
  describe('Radframe registration test', function() {
  it('should register a new user', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:3000/accounts/register');
    element(by.id('id_first_name')).sendKeys("Name",protractor.Key.NULL);
    element(by.id('id_last_name')).sendKeys("Last name",protractor.Key.NULL);
    var job_title = element(by.id('id_job_title')).sendKeys("job title",protractor.Key.NULL);
    element(by.id('id_phone_number')).sendKeys("34894738044",protractor.Key.NULL);
    element(by.id('id_email')).sendKeys("test@test.com",protractor.Key.NULL);
    element(by.id('id_password1')).sendKeys("password",protractor.Key.NULL);
    var registerButton = element(by.buttonText('Register Account'));
    registerButton.click();
    expect(registerButton.getText()).toBe('Register Account');
  });
});
```

The problem is I have angular dirty check in my html. I am unable to click the register button because the form is invalid (have classes ng-pristine, ng-empty and ng-untouched) even after value is being entered through protractor.

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="id_email" name="email" ng-focus="emailFocused()" ng-model="email" ng-model-options="{debounce: { &quot;default&quot;: 300, &quot;blur&quot;: 0 }, updateOn: &quot;default keyup mousedown&quot; }" placeholder="Company Email *" required="required" type="email">.
```

What should I do differently to be able to submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are clicking `registerButton`?

```
var registerButton = element(by.buttonText('Register Account'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(registerButton),5000);
registerButton.click();
expect(registerButton.getText()).toBe('Register Account');
```

Wait till the dirty checking is complete because DOM gets updated if required in this scenario.

Comment: I have edited that line. I am still having the same issue. Is there a way to bypass angular dirty check classes?